# Getting "Method Not Allowed" error when using ASP.NET Web API inside ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am trying to implement HMAC authentication using the code given here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/.

I integrated this code inside my ASP.NET web forms application. I created a folder named "HMACAPI" and added the controllers and filters inside it. I also installed all the required Nuget packages. This is how I am implementing my service methods:

```
[HMACAuthentication]
[RoutePrefix("api/forms")]
public class FormsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        var Name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;

        return Ok("test");
    }

    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string order)
    {
        return Ok(order);
    }
}
```

This is my route configuration for the API:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(APIWebFormsProject.API.WebApiConfig.Register);
```

But when I use `client.PostAsJsonAsync()`, it's showing `Method Not Allowed` error. I tried various SO questions but none of their answers are helping.

**What I tried:**

1. Removed `WebDAV` module.
2. Added `[HttpPost]` attribute to post method.

I am using "http://localhost:56697/api/forms/" URL to access the API. But I also tried "http://localhost:56697/api/forms" and "http://localhost:56697/api/forms/test".

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Obsidian Phoenix I was able to run it without `[HMACAuthentication]` attribute. But I want to implement this with HMAC authentication. So, what can be the reasons for this?

Comment: you need to use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute` instead of
`RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute`

Comment: @MethodMan I tried that. Still not working. And sorry I typed it incorrectly. It's `Method Not Allowed` error.

Comment: Just a check, do you have 'config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();' as a part of your route configurations. 'config' here is 'HttpConfiguration' in your WebApiConfig

Comment: @singsuyash yes I already did that.

Comment: How are you passing the `order` value?

Comment: I was passing it like `client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,"test")`. But now I am using POCO approach as suggested by Taiseer. Now I am not getting Method Not Allowed but I am getting Task was cancelled.

Comment: Can you add sample code detailing your client side calls to the API?

Comment: Are you sure the error "Method not allowed" is caused at `client.PostAsJsonAsync()` line? Because recently I had a very similar issue and found that the error was thrown from an exception handling code after `client.PostAsJsonAsync()`.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix sample code is same as given in the article. And sorry for late reply. Got some other urgent project.

Comment: @zak I placed the breakpoints there it was throwing at `client.PostAsJsonAsync()` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this. I didn't expected that this will be a solution.

I **changed the port** and **used Local IIS server** instead of Visual Studio Development Server. Although I was using IIS before I asked the question but I think port changing solved the issue.

Well, thanks everyone for your efforts in solving my problem. Because of all your answers and comments I was able to come to this solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

I guess your problem with sending HTTP POST to the endpoint (api/forms) and there is nothing to do with HMACAuth attribute, right?

If this is the case then do not sent Order as String, it should be as an POCO object containing string property, something as the below should work:

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and also tried your original code. But in both the cases I am getting  "Task was cancelled" error.

Comment: I just found out its working without HMAC attribute. But I want to use HMAC in my app. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `[FromBody]` attribute on your method.

In order to use `client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, "test")`, your method signature should look like this:

```
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string order)
{
    return Ok(order);
}
```

Likewise, passing a POCO object:

```
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] OrderModel order)
{
    return Ok(order);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its still giving `A task was cancelled.`

Comment: Does it still do it if you remove the hmac attribute?

Comment: Actually its working without HMAC attribute. But I want to use HMAC authentication.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to narrow down the issue. I'll take another look later

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for ur answer and mark it if it solves the problem. :)